# Get int array from string

Tags: c#, string, integer

```
string str = "XXX_123_456_789_ABC";
int[] intAry = GetIntAryByStr(str);
```

Get `int[] result` like this `int[0] <- 123 , int[1] <- 456 , int[2] <- 789`

```
string str = "A111B222C333.bytes";
int[] intAry = GetIntAryByStr(str);
```

Get `int[] result` like this `int[0] <- 111, int[1] <- 222 , int[2] <- 333`

How to do it !?

Comment: You could extract all sequences of digits from the string using `Regex.Matches(str, @"\d+")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try *regular expressions* in order to match all items:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

int[] intAry = Regex
  .Matches(str, "[0-9]+")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(match => int.Parse(match.Value))
  .ToArray();
```

If array items must have `3` digits only, change `[0-9]+` pattern into `[0-9]{3}`

Comment: You don't need the Cast, although maybe it depends on .net version.

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorovich: older .Net versions require `Cast<Match>` (or `OfType<Match>`) since their `MatchCollection` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<Match>`

Answer (score 2):

Just to demonstrate what @Klaus Gütter suggests, and with linq:

```cs
        static int[] GetIntAryByStr(string s)
        {
            return Regex.Matches(s, @"\d+")
                .OfType<Match>()
                .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Value))
                .ToArray();
        }
```